# How to use multiple translation files without domains in Twig in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

In the Symfony2 project, I'm working on, the translations are files in multiple domain files like

```
foo.en_GB.xlf
bar.en_GB.xlf
buz.en_GB.xlf
...
foo.de_DE.xlf
bar.de_DE.xlf
buz.de_DE.xlf
...
foo.fr_FR.xlf
...
```

So in the Twig files I have to define the domain, e.g.:

```
{% trans from 'my_domain' %}my_key{% endtrans %}
```

Actually I don't need the domains in this project. All the translations are part of one big domain. So, I want (1) to use multiple translation files and (2) in the same time not to care about the domain, so that

```
{% trans %}my_key{% endtrans %}
```

should work for the `my_key` translated in any `/.../translations/*.xlf` file.

**How to use multiple translation files without domains in a Twig template in Symfony2?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a custom loader without break nothing, all you need is to use a different file extension:

```
namespace AppBundle\Translation\Loader;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader;

class FooFileLoader extends XliffFileLoader
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages')
    {
        // ignoring $domain var and pass 'messages' instead
        return parent::load($resource, $locale, 'messages');
    }
}
```

[Register the translation loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-translation-loader):

```
services:
    app.translation.loader.foo:
        class: AppBundle\Translation\Loader\FooFileLoader 
        tags:
            - { name: 'translation.loader', alias: 'foo' }
```

Later, you must name all your files to:

```
bar.en_GB.foo
baz.en_GB.foo
bar.de_DE.foo
baz.de_DE.foo
...
```

All your translation files with `.foo` extension will be merged and included into `messages` domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've not extended the `XliffFileLoader` yet, but changed it (only for testing this!) and added at the begin of the [`XliffFileLoader#load(...)`](https://github.com/symfony/translation/blob/master/Loader/XliffFileLoader.php#L31) `$domain = 'messages';`. But it doesn't work. Have you tried out your solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: I suppose it will only work for the case of one translation file (per language), that calls `messages.{locale}.{alias}`. But then we don't need to extend the default file loader.

Comment: Yes, I've tried my solution and it works for all translation files with `.foo` extension.

Comment: Use my SE fork to reproduce it https://github.com/yceruto/symfony-standard and fetch the `translation_loader` branch ;)

Comment: Make sure to execute `bin/console cache:clear` command to update all translation catalogues

Comment: then go to `/app_dev.php/en/` or `/app_dev.php/es/` to see the result.

Comment: It works! The problem, why my check with `$domain = 'messages';` directly in the `XliffFileLoader#load(...)` (see my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125206/how-to-use-multiple-translation-files-without-domains-in-twig-in-symfony2/41132658?noredirect=1#comment69482117_41132658)) didn't work (and it's actually what you do correct way with a new service and inheritance), was the cache. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the translation domain for an entire Twig template with a single tag:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'app' %}
```